# Running multiple ASP.net core web api applications on a single Kestrel server instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, https, kestrel

Is it possible to run multiple asp.net core web api applications on same machine and listening to different ports and all the services should be running on same kestrel instance?

I have a requirement to develop multiple services (Micro services) using ASP.net core web api, and should be deployed on same machine and should use HTTPS and same SSL certificate.
As per my findings, each service needs to be configured to run on separate kestrel instance, so there is an overhead of configuring same SSL thing for each service. I am trying to find a way to run all the services on single instance of kestrel so that I can enable SSL at one shot.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same Kestrel instance?

Comment: Hi @DavidG - To answer your question - "To make deployment easier".
If I have multiple instances of kestrel, I will have to enable SSL for each service and I would be using same SSL certificate for each service, so if I can run it on singe kestrel instance I can configure SSL once and all services are listening to HTTPS and probably different ports

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late to answer this, but you should consider introducing a reverse proxy that does SSL termination / load balancing.

Nginx seems to be the currently popular option for that with .NET Core (and there's good documentation available for "how to do it.")

Nginx -> ASP.NET Core connection can be on HTTP (as long as the .NET Core instances firewalled and are not exposed externally.)